# Ubuntu 19.10 Cant Add SMB Printer

Tags: printing, 19.10, smb

Trying to add a SMB printer that is shared on a Windows box. I can successfully access the fileshares but when I try to browse for a printer in the Ubuntu Printers dialog it tells me "Additional Packages Required" and when I follow this to Software it gives me a frowny face and says "Unfortunately the python3-smbc you were searching for could not be found." I have had no trouble installing other things both through Software and (my preference) through apt on the Terminal.

This appears to be a bug in the packaging of 19.10. Question is, how do I resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same error occurred in my installation of Ubuntu 18.04 this is how I resolved it,

`sudo apt install smbclient`

I don't remember exactly but the same problem in my friends laptop resolved after running the following command `python3-smbc` is the package that was mentioned in the Ubuntu store error

`sudo apt install python3-smbc`

Comment: Thanks! This resolved the error I was getting, but I still cant connect to the printer itself, but I guess that will be the subject of another question.

Comment: It was `python3-smbc` that was causing problems for me. Thanks!